# SXSSFWorkbook.write() fails when called more than once

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there a way that I can write the workbook into outputStream in several times? or a workaround for this?

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Row row = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
    //set cell values.....
    if(rowNum % 500 == 0) wb.write(out);
}
```

from [this forum](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53515), it seems that SXSSFWorkbook doesn't support re-using the Workbook like this.

I'm trying to query the database and use workbook to write the result back into Excel file.

My web application structure is: browser - Apache - server - database.

The problem is that it sometimes takes a long time to finish writing the whole workbook if the data set is very big. As a result, the Apache will break the connection to the server before server could write response back.

If no other better solutions, I think I will have to save a temp file on sever, and let browser constantly check the process. download the file in the end.

[EDIT]

The reason I didn't use CSV is that I have some format requirements on the excel file. workbook is the most straightforward tool to me for that purpose.(not sure if CSVwriter could format ecel as well).

I think it's the database query process which consume the time. That's why I want to write data back to client along with fetching data from the db.

Comment: Keep flushing 0 bytes to the client to keep the connection going? Also, what do you think you'll achieve by writing the workbook part-way through? Once written, it can't be appended to

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks for your suggestion, I will try write 0 bytes to client and see if that works. and you are right, even I could make workbook do multiple write, I still need to figure out how to append

Comment: You can't append, the file format doesn't support it. If you want to append, you need to use CSV

Comment: @Gagravarr OK, another thing learned, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting comments to an answer:

```
if(rowNum % 500 == 0) wb.write(out);
```

This will not do what you seem to expect it to, and will not usefully work. The Excel file formats (`.xls` and `.xlsx`) are not appendable file formats. You can only write all of the file out in one go.

If you write the Workbook out to a file, then later write another copy of it to the same file, it won't work. You'll then end up with two workbooks in a file, which isn't supported

If you really want to save an Excel-like file out as you generate it, you need to use CSV. CSV is streamable and appendable

If not, generate the whole file in one go, then send that to the client. If need be, send 0 byte (possibly chunked) "hello, still here" response writes until you're done.

However, writing a very large spreadsheet with Apache POI should take at most a few seconds, not long enough to time out a connection. If it's taking longer than that, the problem likely isn't in Apache POI, but in your code. See [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109) on testing the POI standalone performance, so you can see what it your own code's fault

Comment: The reason I didn't use CSV is that I have some format requirements on the excel file. workbook is the most straightforward tool to me for that requirement.(not sure if CSVwriter could format ecel as well). you are right again. I think it's the database query process which consume the time.that's why I want to write content into outputStream immediately after each rs.fetchSize

Comment: I'd have a chat with your DBAs if I were you, most database queries when correctly tuned shouldn't take very long. If you really must have an epic query, ask the user for their email address, and email them the URL when the file is finally generated!